# Why is this ImageMagick convert call not adding centered text to my image?

Tags: imagemagick

I have, in a script:

```
    os.system('convert -font ' + os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
      'fr/Verdana.ttf') + ' -gravity Center -pointsize 100 label:"Fr."' +
      ' /tmp/fr/' + filename + ' /tmp/fr/' + filename)
```

That should be equivalent to:

```
convert -font /Users/jonathan/link/fr/Verdana.ttf -gravity Center -pointsize 100 label:"Fr." /tmp/fr/12345.png /tmp/fr/12345.png
```

But no text or other discernible change occurs on the image.

I have also tried:

```
    os.system('convert -font ' + os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
      'fr/Verdana.ttf') + ' -gravity Center -pointsize 100 -annotate 0 "Fr."' +
      ' /tmp/fr/' + filename + ' /tmp/fr/' + filename)
```

This should be equivalent to:

```
convert -font /Users/jonathan/link/fr/Verdana.ttf -gravity Center -pointsize 100 -annotate 0 "Fr." /tmp/fr/12345.png /tmp/fr/12345.png
```

What should I be doing differently to have "Fr." centered in large black letters in a font size I provide?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that `label:` creates its own canvas. Let's start with a green image called `a.png`

[image]

Now, if you try to add a label like this:

```
convert a.png -gravity Center -pointsize 100 label:"Fr." result.png
```

you will get TWO output images - `result-0.png` and `result-1.png` because, as far as ImageMagick is concerned, you have said you want the original image (`a.png`) and another lump of canvas with some letters on that you gave no indication where you would like it put.

If you tell ImageMagick to append these two canvases side by side in a single picture like this, you will see what you have created

```
convert a.png -gravity Center -pointsize 100 label:"Fr." +append result.png
```

[image]

The secret is to *composite* the label *on top* of your original image, whilst making sure the background of the label is transparent:

```
convert a.png -gravity Center -pointsize 100 -background none label:"Fr." -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered. I now have a working script at https://CJSHayward.com/fr/

Comment: Excellent! Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I can get the desired result (to a 2nd file) if I use the equivalent of:

```
convert /tmp/fr/12345.png -font /Users/jonathan/link/fr/Verdana.ttf -gravity Center -pointsize 100 label:"Fr." -composite /tmp/fr/12345.new.png
```